# What mysql type should I use to store a Decimal of variable precision (may change per record)

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

1. If I store the Decimal as 1.200, I want a query to retrieve the value as 1.200, but if I store the value as 1.450005, I want a query to return 1.450005.
2. I need to be able to compare on the field as a numeric type.

At first glance, Decimal(10,6) appears to be a good use for my requirement for a field to represent prices, but what I really want is a field that can store **up-to** 6 digits to the right of the decimal, **not necessarily all 6 digits every single time**.

If this requirement is satisfied, I have effectively encoded precision information in the field, which is useful for retrieving the data out into an instance of a C++ Decimal object which requires that a 1.20 (precision 2) is different from a 1.2000 (precision 4), even though they share the same value/worth.  Retaining the precision information in my object is crucial for further arithmetic operations.

An alternative, I suppose, is to store the value as a varchar() in Mysql which would retain the digits, but then lose arithmetic operators functionality in Mysql.

A third, ugly, alternative is to use Decimal(10,6) and then use one extra field which will store the precision that I am using so I can convert properly into my C++ instance.  I may have to go with this ugly approach if there are no better solutions.

Anyone have a good suggestion on how I can approach these requirements?

Comment: You summed up 3; if you're the one who has to implement it, I think it's up to you how complex you want the code to get.  If you're using the numbers to calculate sig figs, then I'd probably go with option #3.  But that's just my opinion.

Comment: You have correctly analyzed the options.  There are no others.  Choose one.  #3 sounds best to me.

Answer (score 0):

Per Crontab and Jim Garrison's comments, the best solution to this question is to:

1. Use [`DECIMAL(10,6)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) to store the number itself, and
2. Use one extra field which will store the precision that applies to the specific record

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139075/should-old-questions-with-a-solution-in-the-comments-but-no-posted-answer-be-ans) for why I'm answering an old post.

Comment: This only works if you are getting ONE DECIMAL record at a time. If you'll be getting multiple rows and using another column variable for ROUND or TRUNCATE decimal length - it doesn't work.